# Adding a "Like" operator via views query alter for taxonomy term name

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to add a "Like" operator via views query alter for my taxonomy term name. My view is a block setup with a contextual filter set to show all results as shown below as I want to filter it per page, see info below how I am doing that.

[image]

Then within given pages, I'd like my content editors to be able to input parts of a term name (thus the SQL "Like" operator) to filter a view via the paragraphs view field contextual options field. For example part of a term name would be "Creative Commons" as shown below.

[image]

The code I have so far after using Xdebug is:

```
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;


/**
* Implements hook_views_query_alter().
*/
function mymodule_custom_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  // Define the view display.
  if ($view->current_display === 'remix_icons_nf_block') {
    // Define the taxonomy term name.
    $name = $view->argument["name"]->query->fields["taxonomy_term_field_data_name"]["field"];
    // Add a like operator.
    $view->query->where[1]["conditions"][0]["operator"] = 'LIKE';
    // Now query the name using the condition above.
    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][0]['value'] = '%' . $name . '%';
  }
}
```

However, this does not seem to be working (no views results show up on the page) and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the output from Xdebug as well if that helps.

[image]